# Computing Fibonacci Numbers with Dynamic Programming (Python)

Tags: python, fibonacci

I am doing some practice problems for interview preparation and I came upon this extension of the Fibonacci sequence problem:

> This question expands on our earlier Fibonacci Lite challenge. While the goal of Fibonacci Lite was to understand recursion, this challenge is about solving problems efficiently with dynamic programming.
>
> The difference in this challenge is that each test case will consist of many inputs instead of just one. Furthermore, we're allowing larger values of n. You'll need to use dynamic programming to solve all the inputs without running out of time.

I wrote a solution in Python which has been passing my input tests but it would be great if I could get some external verification of my results. Here is the code:

```
import time

calculations = [0, 1] #stores previously calculated solutions

def main(nArr):
    simpOut = [] #simple solutions
    dynOut = [] #dynamic solutions

    start = time.time()
    for val in nArr:
        simpOut.append(fibDyn(val))
    end = time.time()
    print("dynamic:")
    print(simpOut)
    print(end - start)

    print("")

    start = time.time()
    for val in nArr:
        dynOut.append(fibSimp(val))
    end = time.time()
    print("simple:")
    print(dynOut)
    print(end - start)

#dynamic solution
def fibDyn(n):
    #base case: checks if solution has already been calculated
    if n < len(calculations):
        return calculations[n]
    #recursion
    currentSol = fibDyn(n-2) + fibDyn(n-1)
    calculations.append(currentSol)
    return currentSol

#simple solution
def fibSimp(n):
    #base case
    if n <= 1:
        return n
    #recursion
    return fibSimp(n-2) + fibSimp(n-1)
```

Thanks for any input.

Comment: I believe it is functionally correct, but storing the elements in a list makes the whole thing very complicated. I would opt for a dictionary instead. Also, you're confusing `dynOut` with `simpOut`. Since it is working code, it is offtopic for StackOverflow, you could go to [CodeReview.SO](https://codereview.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Good catch on the dynOut and simpOut. What would be the advantage of using a dictionary over a list in terms of simplicity? Do you mean store the final outputs or the dynamic programming part? Currently I'm able to keep the outputs in the same order as the inputs. I'm also using each index to represent the n value that would give that output. For example, calculations[6] = 8 = F6.

Comment: The advantage would be that you could instead of appending write `dynOut[n] = currentSol`, and you wouldn't need to worry about accidentally inserting an item into the list when you already did, or something similar. For a textbook solution to the problem use a functools.lru_cache decorator.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more appropriate for codereview.stackexchange.com